# Можно ли в css определить стили через другой класс? Ради удобства

Tags: css, css3

```
.сlass_1 {
 attr_1: "value1";
 attr_2: "value2";
}

//class_main должен "применять" класс class_1
.class_main {
//хочется не дублировать здесь стили из "class_1" а написать что-то типа using...
attr_3: "value1";
}
```

Comment: А простая запись через запятую вас чем не устраивает ?  _.сlass_1,.class_main {attr_1: "value1"; attr_2: "value2";}  .class_main {attr_3: "value1";}_

Comment: Да, так можно. Но я не уточнил - а если в html разметке нет возможности вставить "class_1"?

Comment: к css доступ есть ?

Comment: К исходнику не могу дать доступ. Видимо я хочу что-то типа "вложенных классов", но в css так нельзя сделать..

Comment: мне исходник не нужен но нужен Вам, и продублирую первый вопрос из комментария - запись через запятую чем не устраивает ?

Comment: Ответ: не устраивает тем, что не могу в html применять оба класса (только class_main). К css доступ есть.

Comment: @СергейSer А где собственно связь ?  В css ещё селекторы есть, не только классы. Через запятую можно перечислять любые селекторы, не только классы.

Comment: файл стилей один ?

Comment: Нет,файлов стилей много (bootstrap и.т.д). Но работаю c одним

Comment: в общем ваш родной css должен находится в head ниже всех и тогда он будет типа главный

Comment: Да, все так. Вы не поняли мой вопрос, у меня все работает. Я попозже скину сюда (наверно) пример для понимания, что именно я хотел-бы "улучшить"